# Lines dividing Table don't align

Tags: tables

I've created a table with 3 columns:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{ p{6cm} || >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{3cm} || >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{3cm} }     
\hline
 \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
 \hline \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\ \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular} 
 \caption{Dummy}
 \label{fig:CAMean}
\end{table}
```

It comes out as this:
[image: Dummy Table]

I dont understand why the 2nd vertical line is skipping some parts?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide full examples, not just fragments

Comment: you have a spurious extra rows from `\\ ` after `\hline` and  `\\ \\ `, just delete those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some 'improvements'

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\text}{}


\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{ p{6cm} ||C{3cm} ||C{3cm}}
\hline
 \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
 \hline  & & \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \\ 
  & & \\
  \hline
 \end{tabular} 
 \caption{Dummy}
 \label{fig:CAMean}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ p{6cm} ||C{3cm} ||C{3cm}}
\toprule
 \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
 \midrule  & & \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline
  \text Dummy & Dummy & Dummy \tabularnewline 
  & & \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular} 
 \caption{Dummy}
 \label{fig:CAMeanother}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document
```

[image]